# Google Contacts Full Name

Tags: php, xml, xpath, contacts, google-contacts-api

I've searched pretty extensively, forgive me if this happens to be a repeat question.

I'm trying to retrieve first and last names with the Google Contacts api. Gathering emails was easy enough with:

```
$result = $xml->xpath('//gd:email');
$count = 0;
foreach ($result as $title) {
    $count++;
    $email = $title->attributes()->address;
}
```

I'm having absolutely no luck figuring out how to use

```
//gd:fullName
```

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Please always give example input. And best would be to post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) which includes the sample input in the code and can be directly executed by copy&pasting them into PHP; something similar to [this example on php.net](http://de1.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full name is not stored in an attribute, but as text value – that makes things even simpler for parsing.

```
$names = $xml->xpath('//gd:fullName');
foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo $name;
}
```

Whenever a SimpleXML node is casted to string, it returns its text value (here, the full name).